# OpenGL light not working

Tags: java, opengl, lighting

I am using this code to draw different cubes with different colors using the LWJGL:

```
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glColor3f(rcol.x, rcol.y, rcol.z); // Color Vector
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);             // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)

        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Bottom)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Bottom)

        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Front)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Front)

        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Back)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Back)

        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);     // Top Left Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Left)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Left)

        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Right)
        GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y - rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Right)
    GL11.glEnd();
```

It draws the cube fine and the color is perfect, but as soon as I add light to it, everything turns white and looks horrible.  Here is my lighting code:

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);

float lightAmbient[] = { 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f };  // Ambient Light Values
float lightDiffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };      // Diffuse Light Values
float lightPosition[] = { 20.0f, 15.0f, 20.0f, 1.0f }; // Light Position
float lightSpecular[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f }; // Light Position

ByteBuffer temp = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16);
temp.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightSpecular).flip());   
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip());              // Setup The Ambient Light
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightDiffuse).flip());              // Setup The Diffuse Light
GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION,(FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightPosition).flip());         // Position The Light
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here?  Here is come example pictures:
[image: No Lighting]
[image: Lighting]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the [normal vector](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html) to your quads with `glNormal3f`. The normal vector is used for lighting calculations.

The normal vector is perpendicular to your surface. So, for example, with your first quad:

```
GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Right Of The Quad (Top)
GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z - rsiz.z);         // Top Left Of The Quad (Top)
GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x - rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);         // Bottom Left Of The Quad (Top)
GL11.glVertex3f(rpos.x + rsiz.x, rpos.y + rsiz.y, rpos.z + rsiz.z);             // Bottom Right Of The Quad (Top)
```

The y coordinate is constant, so a normal vector perpendicular to this surface could
be `(0, 1, 0)` or `(0, -1, 0)`.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked for the lighting, now how can I get the color to work?

Comment: @Matt Add different `glColor3f` calls before each quad. Also use `glMaterialfv` to set material properties.